# How to solve this errors of plsql?

Tags: plsql

[its show this type of error help me to solve it i attch screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgatm.png)enter code here

```
declare
empnos NUMBER(9,2);
L NUMBER(9,2);
ANS NUMBER(9,2);
function avg_sal(x number, y number) return number AS
begin
         ANS := (x / y) * 100;
         return  ANS;
end avg_sal;
BEGIN
   empnos := :EMPNOr;
   select TOTAT_SAL,NOOFEMP  from dept 
   where  DEPTNO=(
       select deptno from emp
       where empnos=emp.empno
 );
       L := avg_sal(TOTAT_SAL,NOOFEMP);
END;
```

Comment: Well, it does tell you what to do. Add an `INTO` clause in the `SELECT` to assign the values selected to variables.

Answer (score 0):

As error shows and *sticky bit* above mentioned, you need to take result into variables:
Here is an example:

```
declare
  empnos      NUMBER(9, 2);
  L           NUMBER(9, 2);
  ANS         NUMBER(9, 2);
  v_total_sal NUMBER(9, 2);
  v_nooofemp  NUMBER(9, 2);
  function avg_sal(x number, y number)
    return number AS
    begin
      ANS := (x / y) * 100;
      return ANS;
    end avg_sal;

BEGIN
  empnos := :EMPNOr;
  select
    TOTAT_SAL,
    NOOFEMP
  into v_total_sal,
       v_nooofemp
  from dept
  where DEPTNO = (
    select deptno
    from emp
    where empnos = emp.empno
  );
  L := avg_sal(v_total_sal, v_nooofemp);
END;
```